# GData calendar get specific event

Tags: objective-c, google-calendar-api, gdata

Is it possible to get specific event from specific calendar?

I collect all events from calendar, save some events on device and then need to detect any changes of this events in source calendar. So I need some way to get events data from google calendar by its id. etag or something.

Is there any way to do so not collecting full events set again?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
    # Gets the event with id $eventId from the calendar $calendar
function get_event_by_id_ex( $gdataCal, $eventId, $calendar='default' ){
if( !isset($eventId) )
{
    throw new Exception( INCORRECT_EVENT_ID );
}

try
{
    $query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();
    $query->setUser($calendar);
    $query->setVisibility('private');
    $query->setProjection('full');
    $query->setEvent($eventId);

    $ctz = 'Europe/Lisbon';
    $query->setParam('ctz', $ctz);      

    $eventEntry = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventEntry($query);
}
catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e)
{   //var_dump($e); //DBUG
    throw new Exception( ERROR_ACCESSING_APPOINTMENT . ' (' .$eventId. ')' );
}

return $eventEntry;
}
```